# The do-while loop keeps on repeating

Tags: c++

I have a code fragment(we have assigned a school project on Banking System and this is the first LogIn Screen also please do note that this code fragment is inside the main() function) something like this:

```
int choice;

do
{
    clrscr(); // for clear screen
    cout << "1. Help!" << endl;
    cout << "2. About Us..." << endl;
    cout << "3. Log In" << endl;
    cout << "4. Sign Up" << endl;
    cout << "Option: ";
    cin >> choice;
}while((choice != 1) || (choice != 2) || (choice != 3) || (choice != 4));
```

but the problem is that whether I input 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or any other number the loop keeps on repeating itself, it just ignores the value of choice... If I am not wrong then the loop should exit as soon as choice gets the value of either 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 and the loop should continue if it gets the value any other than 1 or 2 or 3 or 4... There are no errors when I compile the program so I am not able to get what the actual problem is.

***Extra Information:-***

**Operating System:** Windows 7
**Compiler:** Visual C++ Express Edition (also tried on Borland Turbo C++ 4.5 and Dev C++ as well as in Code::Blocks latest version but still the same problem)

Comment: `while((choice != 1) && (choice != 2) && (choice != 3) && (choice != 4));`

Comment: it will loop as long as the condition is true.  The "OR" operator || returns true if either of its operands is true.  That is, if choice !=1 || choice != 2, will _always_ be true.  (If choice==1, it's != 2, so the 2nd subexpression is true.  If choice==2, then it's != 1, so the 1st subexpression is true.  Either way, it's always true.  You want to be sure it's not equal to ANY of the values, not that it differs from at least one of them.

Answer (score 6):

The loop condition will always be true; `choice` can't have all of those values at once.

Presumably, you meant to use `&&` so that the loop terminates when `choice` has any of those values.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer:

You repeat while `choice` is different from 1 or different from 2, or 3, or 4. If the value of `choice` is correct, you would loop because of the 3 other conditions.

```
while((choice != 1) || (choice != 2) || (choice != 3) || (choice != 4));
```

You probably meant `&&`:

```
while(choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3 && choice != 4);
```

or:

```
while(choice < 1 || choice > 4);
```

#### Logical explanation:

Basically, you want to loop while the value of `choice` is not correct. In this context, Correct means: `choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3 || choice == 4`.

So, a first condition could be:

```
while (!(choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 3 || choice == 4));
```

If you remember that `!(a || b) == (!a && !b)`. You can also write:

```
while (choice != 1 && choice != 2 && choice != 3 && choice != 4);
```

Which also makes sense: loop while choice is different from 1 and 2 and 3 and 4.

You can also decide that Correct means: `choice >= 1 && choice <= 4`. In that case you would have:

```
while (!(choice >= 1 && choice <= 4));
```

or, using the same property:

```
while (choice < 1 || choice > 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You've told it to keep going if choice is not 1 OR is not 2. You probably meant not 1 AND not 2, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You'll run into trouble with cin if someone enters something like "do number one" so i suggest you change your code to the following

```
# include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
# include <string>
# include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
string choice="";

int num = 0;

 while (true) {

   system("cls"); // for clear screen
   cout << "1. Help!" << endl;
   cout << "2. About Us..." << endl;
   cout << "3. Log In" << endl;
   cout << "4. Sign Up" << endl;
   cout << "Option: ";
   getline(cin, choice);

   stringstream Stream(choice);
   if (Stream >> num)
     break;
   cout << "Invalid number, please try again" << endl;
 }

}
```